# TCL multi capture group for simplified csv string parsing with regexp

Tags: regex, tcl

I'm trying to parse a simplified CSV format with TCL regexp. I chose regexp over split to perform rudimentary format compliance test.

My problem is that I want to use a count quantifier but want to exclude the ',' from the match.

My test line:

```
set line "2017/08/21 16:06:20.0, REALTIME, late by  0.3, EOS450D,   1/640, F/8.0, ISO   100, Partial 450D 0.0%"
```

So far I have:

```
regexp -all {(?:([^\,]*)\,){8}} $line dummy date tm off cam exp fnum iso com
```

My thought process is:
Get a match group for all characters that are not comma up to the next comma.
Now I want to match this 8 time so I put it into a non-capturing group followed by a counting quantifier. But that defeats the purpose as now nothing is matched. What I need is a way to make the match go through the CSV 8 times and capture the text but not the comma.

My CSV is simplified in the following.
No quoted strings in the CSV
No empty entries in CSV

I've checked google for csv matching but most hits were too blown up due to allowing special cases in the CSV content.

Thanks,
Gert

Comment: I can't test now, but looking at the code it seems likely that it chokes because there is no comma after the last field (as is proper). I strongly recommend using the csv package in the Tcllib to process even simplified csv.

Answer (score 2):

In the `regexp` command, the interaction between the `-all` switch and the match variables is that the values captured in the last iteration of matching are used to fill the variables. This means that you can't fill eight variables by having one capture group and iteratively matching it eight times.

Your regular expression doesn't match anyway, since it requires a comma after the last field.

For this particular example, you could use the invocation

```
% regexp -all -inline {[^,]+} $line
{2017/08/21 16:06:20.0} { REALTIME} { late by  0.3} { EOS450D} {   1/640} { F/8.0} { ISO   100} { Partial 450D 0.0%}
```

This means to match all groups of characters that aren't commas (note that the comma isn't special: you don't need to escape it) and return them as a list.

As you noted, this is the same as using

```
% split $line ,
```

(which is also about five times faster).

You didn't want to use `split` because you wanted to do some validation: it is unclear what forms of validation you wanted to do, but you can easily validate the number of fields found:

```
% set fields [split $line ,]
% if {[llength $fields] ne 8} {puts stderr "wrong number of fields"}
```

You can store the fields in variables and validate them separately, which is a lot easier to get right than trying to validate them all at the same time while extracting them:

```
lassign $fields date tm off cam exp fnum iso com
if {![regexp {ISO\s+\d+} $iso]} {puts stderr "in search of valid ISO"}
```

The best method is still to split the data string using the `csv` package. Even if you just want to use this simplified CSV now, sooner than you think you might want to, say, allow fields with commas in them.

```
package require csv
set fields [::csv::split $line]
```

Documentation:
[csv (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.html),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm),
[llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

**ETA:** Getting rid of leading/trailing whitespace. This is a bit unusual, since CSV data is usually arranged to be fields of strictly significant text separated by a separator character. If there is anything to be trimmed, it is usually done when saving the data.

A good way is to put the matched groups through an `lmap`/`string trim` filter:

```
lmap field [regexp -all -inline {[^,]+} $line] {string trim $field}
```

Another way is to get rid of whitespace around commas first, and then split:

```
split [regsub -all {\s*,\s*} $line ,] ,
```

You can use the Tcllib variant of `split` that splits by regular expression:

```
package require textutil
::textutil::splitx $line {\s*,\s*}
```

You can also swap out the earlier regular expression for `[^\s,][^,]*[^\s,]` (will not match fields of less than two characters). This is a regular expression that is on the verge of becoming too complex to be useful.

Comment: I like the proposed regex. Is there a way to trim leading / trailing spaces as part of the regex ? (Yes, it can be trimmed later, but it would be nice if it can be combined into the items returned by regex.)

Comment: @GertGottschalk: I made some suggestions in an ETA.